# The type CalculatorLanguageServer must implement the inherited abstract method StreamConnectionProvider.getErrorStream()

Tags: java, eclipse

I tried to create the Xtext calculator DSL as guided in the README in [this repo](https://github.com/svenefftinge/xtext-lsp-workshop.git). It is an Xtext DSL with a language server and LSP4E implementation, and has 2 sub projects named:

I downloaded the repo and opened it in the Eclipse IDE. Under the main project, there are 2 sub-projects named: org.xtext.calc.parent (which is the xtext project) and org.xtext.calc.lsp4e (the lsp4e implementation project).

In the org.xtext.calc.lsp4e project's src folder there are 3 Java files named: Activator, CalculatorLanguageServer, SocketStreamConnectionProvider. In the latter two, I get an error which I cannot resolve.

Below are the two files: -

1.) CalculatorLanguageServer.java

```
package org.xtext.calc.lsp4e;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform;
import org.eclipse.lsp4e.server.ProcessStreamConnectionProvider;
import org.eclipse.lsp4e.server.StreamConnectionProvider;
import org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.messages.Message;
import org.eclipse.lsp4j.services.LanguageServer;
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;

public class CalculatorLanguageServer implements StreamConnectionProvider {

    private final static boolean SOCKET_MODE = true;
    private StreamConnectionProvider delegate;

    public CalculatorLanguageServer() {
        if (SOCKET_MODE) {
            this.delegate = new SocketStreamConnectionProvider(5007) {
            };
        } else {
            List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
            commands.add("java");
            commands.add("-Xdebug");
            commands.add("-Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4001,suspend=n,quiet=y");
            commands.add("-jar");
            Bundle bundle = Activator.getDefault().getBundle();
            URL resource = bundle.getResource("/language-server/calculator-language-server-jar");
            try {
                commands.add(new File(FileLocator.resolve(resource).toURI()).getAbsolutePath());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
            this.delegate = new ProcessStreamConnectionProvider(commands, Platform.getLocation().toOSString()) {};
        }
    }

    public void start() throws IOException {
        delegate.start();
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        return delegate.getInputStream();
    }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
        return delegate.getOutputStream();
    }

    public Object getInitializationOptions(URI rootUri) {
        return delegate.getInitializationOptions(rootUri);
    }

    public void stop() {
        delegate.stop();
    }

    public void handleMessage(Message message, LanguageServer languageServer, URI rootURI) {
        delegate.handleMessage(message, languageServer, rootURI);
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Calculator Language Server: " + super.toString();
    }
}
```

2.) SocketStreamConnectionProvider.java

```
package org.xtext.calc.lsp4e;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

import org.eclipse.lsp4e.server.StreamConnectionProvider;

public class SocketStreamConnectionProvider implements StreamConnectionProvider {

    private int port;
    private Socket socket;
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private OutputStream outputStream;

    public SocketStreamConnectionProvider(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws IOException {
        this.socket = new Socket("localhost", port);
        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        return inputStream;
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
        return outputStream;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In both these files, I get an error in the class names:

> 1.) The type CalculatorLanguageServer must implement the inherited abstract method StreamConnectionProvider.getErrorStream()
>
> 2.) The type SocketStreamConnectionProvider must implement the inherited abstract method StreamConnectionProvider.getErrorStream()

How to resolve these errors?

Thanks!

Comment: did you have a look at ProcessStreamConnectionProvider?

Comment: is there any specific reason you want to use sockets?

Comment: see e.g. https://github.com/itemis/xtext-languageserver-example-lsp4e/tree/cd_update